# Document Library File GUID

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, caml-query

I used a CAML query to get file information in a document library.
In the CAML query I get the GUID in order to get the unique id of the document.

```
<FieldRef Name='GUID'/>
```

In a different occasion I tryed to get the file through the GUID using GetFile() method

```
web.GetFile(new Guid("{the guid from CAML query }"));
```

It gives an error.

So, retrieved the ID instead

```
<FieldRef Name='ID'/>
```

Through the DocumentLibrary, took the SPFile

```
Guid fileStr = documentsLibrary.Items.GetItemById(int.Parse("The ID from CAML query")).File.UniqueId;
SPFile aa = documentsLibrary.GetItemByUniqueId(fileStr).File;
```

It works fine.
So the two questions i have are:

Are there two GUID's for item and File & 
Is there a way to directly get the SPFile GUID via CAML, so that it can be used in `web.GetFile()` ?

Answer (score 0):

CAML query returns splistitemcollections. Why don't you get the GUID for the returned items?
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.uniqueid%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Or even better just use the `.File` from the items returned in the collection!